# Spring data: i can't save my relation model in my db

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have some problem with JPA in my Spring Boot API REST.

I have a model Panier, and inside, a model LignePanier.

When i try to save my panier with panierRepository.save() without lignePanier, no problem, my panier is persisted in my db.

But if i have some lignePanier in my model Panier, JPA doesnt persisted the LignePanier and throw an exception:
"ERROR: relation "panier_lignes_panier" does not exist".

If i creat directly the relation in my db, if i try to persist, it say that i the panier_id of the relation is null (but not in my code if i use a breakpoint).

```
@Entity
public class Panier {

    /**
     * Id unique référençant le panier
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    /**
     * UUID du client permettant de référencer son panier de manière unique.
     */
    @NotNull
    private String clientUuid;

    /**
     * Liste des évenements enregistrés dans le panier de l'utilisateur.
     */
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    List<LignePanier> lignesPanier;

    public Panier () {
        this.lignesPanier = new ArrayList<LignePanier>();
    }

    public Panier (String clientUuid, List<LignePanier> lignesPanier) { this.clientUuid = clientUuid; this.lignesPanier = lignesPanier; }

    public Integer getId() { return this.id; }

    public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getClientUuid() {
        return clientUuid;
    }

    public void setClientUuid(String clientUuid) {
        this.clientUuid = clientUuid;
    }

    public List<LignePanier> getLignesPanier() {
        return lignesPanier;
    }

    public void setLignesPanier(List<LignePanier> lignesPanier) {
        this.lignesPanier = lignesPanier;
    }

    public void addLignePanier(LignePanier lignePanier) {
        if(!this.lignesPanier.contains(lignePanier))
            this.lignesPanier.add(lignePanier);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Panier{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", clientUuid='" + clientUuid + '\'' +
                ", lignesPanier=" + lignesPanier +
                '}';
    }
}

    package com.wildadventures.mscommande.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Model représentant les lignes d'un panier utilisateur
 */
@Entity
public class LignePanier {

    /**
     * id référençant la ligne de panier.
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    /**
     * Référence de l'évenement ajouté au panier
     */
    @NotNull
    private Integer evenementId;

    /**
     * Nombre de place à réserver pour l'évenement
     */
    @NotNull
    @Min(value = 1, message = "Le nombre de participant minimum et de 1")
    private Integer nbPersonne;

    /**
     * Nom de l'évenement référencé.
     */
    @NotNull
    private String aventureNom;

    /**
     * Nombre de places réservées pour l'évenement.
     */
    @NotNull
    @Min(value = 0, message = "La valeur unitaire hors taxe ne peux être inferieure à Zero.")
    private Float prixUnitaireHt;

    /**
     * Date de début de l'évenement
     */
    @NotNull
    private Date dateDebut;

    /**
     * Date de fin de l'évenement
     */
    @NotNull
    private Date dateFin;

    public LignePanier () {}

    public LignePanier(int id, int evenementId, int nbPersonne, String aventureNom, float prixUnitaireHt, Date dateDebut, Date dateFin) {
        this.id = id;
        this.evenementId = evenementId;
        this.nbPersonne = nbPersonne;
        this.aventureNom = aventureNom;
        this.prixUnitaireHt = prixUnitaireHt;
        this.dateDebut = dateDebut;
        this.dateFin = dateFin;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getEvenementId() {
        return evenementId;
    }

    public void setEvenementId(Integer evenementId) {
        this.evenementId = evenementId;
    }

    public Integer getNbPersonne() {
        return nbPersonne;
    }

    public void setNbPersonne(Integer nbPersonne) {
        this.nbPersonne = nbPersonne;
    }

    public String getAventureNom() {
        return aventureNom;
    }

    public void setAventureNom(String aventureNom) {
        this.aventureNom = aventureNom;
    }

    public Float getPrixUnitaireHt() {
        return prixUnitaireHt;
    }

    public void setPrixUnitaireHt(Float prixUnitaireHt) {
        this.prixUnitaireHt = prixUnitaireHt;
    }

    public Date getDateDebut() {
        return dateDebut;
    }

    public void setDateDebut(Date dateDebut) {
        this.dateDebut = dateDebut;
    }

    public Date getDateFin() {
        return dateFin;
    }

    public void setDateFin(Date dateFin) {
        this.dateFin = dateFin;
    }
}

    package com.wildadventures.mscommande.managers;

import com.wildadventures.mscommande.models.LignePanier;
import com.wildadventures.mscommande.models.Panier;
import com.wildadventures.mscommande.repositories.LignePanierRepository;
import com.wildadventures.mscommande.repositories.PanierRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@Component
public class PanierManager {

    @Autowired
    private PanierRepository panierRepository;

    @Autowired LignePanierRepository lignePanierRepository;

    /**
     * Ajoute une nouvelle ligne de panier au panier de l'utilisateur.
     */
    public void ajouterLignePanier(Panier panier, LignePanier lignePanier){

        panier.getLignesPanier().add(lignePanier);
        this.savePanier(panier);
    }

    /**
     * Enregistre le panier pour l'utilisateur ayant comme uuid clientUuid.
     *
     * @param panier le panier de l'utilisateur à créer
     *
     * @return le panier créé
     */
    private Panier savePanier(Panier panier){

        return panierRepository.saveAndFlush(panier);
    }

    /**
     * Récuperer un panier en fonction de son clientUuid
     *
     * @param clientUuid l'uuid du client
     *
     * @return le panier si il existe
     */
    public Panier recupererPanier(String clientUuid) {
        return this.panierRepository.findByClientUuid(clientUuid);
    }

    /**
     * Créer un nouveau panier pour l'utilisateur
     *
     * @param clientUuid l'uuid de l'utilisateur
     *
     * @return le panier créé
     */
    public Panier creerPanier(String clientUuid) {
        Panier panier = new Panier(clientUuid, new ArrayList<LignePanier>());
        return this.savePanier(panier);
    }
}
```

Thx for your responses.

Comment: What happens if you try add OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, **mappedBy="Panier"**)? By doing this you avoid creation of the separate table panier_lignes_panier for storing the list.

Comment: Thx for your response.
I have tried to add this but i have this exception:

"org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown 
target entity property: 
com.wildadventures.mscommande.models.LignePanier.Panier in com.wildadventures.mscommande.models.Panier.lignesPanier"

It search a bidirectional relation that not exist...

Comment: @wdc That makes no sense at all. You add mappedBy when it is a BIDIRECTIONAL relation; this not a bidirectional relation. And mappedBy is NOTHING AT ALL to do with using an FK instead of join table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to model the 1-N unidirectional relation as a FK in the element (rather than using a join table) then you add

```
@JoinColumn
```

to the `lignesPanier` field (and optionally define what the FK column name is if you don't want the default JPA FK column naming). As per [these docs](http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/mapping.html#one_many_fk_uni).

Since you don't define what schema you have then not much more to add

Comment: Yes, i did this on first time, but JPA don't use the id of model Panier.
If i try to persist, i have this exception:

"org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "panier_id" violates not-null constraint"

So, in the breakpoint, my panier have an id...

Comment: "JPA" does nothing; your JPA provider does (and you dont say which one you are using). And I've no idea what you mean by "JPA doesnt use the id"). In the JPA API you persist the owner object and the sub-object will be cascade persisted ... with the FK column populated. But then you can see that in the SQL statements it issues ... by looking in its LOG (aka debugging). You haven't told us YOUR SCHEMA, so we don't know what is "panier_id" ... which table, representing what ? the FK? the id ?

Comment: yes sorry,
I use Hibernate with the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency in my pom....

in my log i have this.
"Hibernate: insert into ligne_panier (aventure_nom, date_debut, date_fin, evenement_id, nb_personne, prix_unitaire_ht) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

it seems that it doesnt try to insert the panier_id in the ligne_panier table...

Comment: right, and you told Hibernate that this FK column is not nullable did you? (in your mapping)

Comment: Yes in my model Panier, and in my table ligne_panier the FK is on NotNull.

After some test, Hibernate try to save the lignePanier (i see all value on log) but the FK is every time at Null. However, the id in table panier existe, and in my breakpoint before save, the panier.id have a value.

Comment: I said "you told Hibernate" ... there is NOTHING in your JPA mapping saying that (and that is what Hibernate will read). Hacking the database manually doesnt tell your JPA provider. Why not UPDATE your question with what you are actually using ... including this `@JoinColumn`